# LDAP authentication with roles from database in spring boot (jhipster)

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security, ldap, jhipster

I copy/paste almost everything from [spring's documentation](https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/)
and the result is

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@Order( SecurityProperties.ACCESS_OVERRIDE_ORDER )
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true, securedEnabled = true )
// @EnableLdapRepositories( basePackages =
// "org.springframework.ldap.samples.useradmin.domain" )
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
...
    @Configuration
    protected static class AuthenticationConfiguration extends GlobalAuthenticationConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        public void init(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
            auth.ldapAuthentication().userDnPatterns("uid={0},ou=people").groupSearchBase("ou=groups")
                    .contextSource().ldif("classpath:ptolemaios.ldif");
        }
    }
...
}
```

For the first step I want the authorization of user from AD(in this situation from ldif), but it does not work and i can not find why, i dont have any error only the message "you dont have autority"

And the second and final step is to get the roles from my database aand after searching i believe this is a good solution(correct me if i am wrong)

Inside the SecurityConfiguration class insert

```
public UserDetailsContextMapper userDetailsContextMapper() {
        return new UserDetailsContextMapper() {
            @Override
            public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(
                    DirContextOperations ctx, String username,
                    Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
                log.error("2 " + username + " -> " + ctx.toString());
                String lowercaseLogonName = username.toLowerCase();
                Optional<PtolUser> userFromDatabase =
                        ptolUserRepository.findOneByLogonName(lowercaseLogonName);
                return userFromDatabase.map(user ->
                    {
                        if (!user.isAccountNonExpired()) {
                            throw new UserNotActivatedException(
                                    "User " + lowercaseLogonName + " was not activated");
                        }
                        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getUserAuthorities().parallelStream()
                                .map(authority -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority(authority.getRole().getName()))
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
                        return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(lowercaseLogonName,
                                user.getPassword(), true, user.isAccountNonExpired(), true,
                                user.isAccountNonLocked(), grantedAuthorities);
                    }).orElseThrow(
                            () -> new UsernameNotFoundException(
                                    "User " + lowercaseLogonName + " was not found in the AD"));
            }

            @Override
            public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Only retrieving data from LDAP is currently supported");
            }

        };
    }
```

and into the AuthenticationManagerBuilder add

```
auth//
    .ldapAuthentication()//
    .userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
...
```

Thank you!